# How we can change the background color of different events in dhtmlx asp.net scheduler

Tags: asp.net, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx asp.net scheduler.

I have bind some events with it from the database.

Now I am not getting how to change the background color of different events.

I have read the documentation, but even then I am not able to find it.

Please help me if you have any ideas.

Comment: is there an asp.net scheduler control ??

Comment: Cold please see here i am using this one.

http://scheduler-net.com/

Comment: this is not only asp.net it also DHTMLX  add it to tag it will increase your chances to get help

Answer (score 3):

event's color is defined by
'color' and 'textColor' properties, you should add them to the model(not necessary to define both of them, you may add just one you need)
e.g.

```
partial class Event
    {
        public string color { get; set; }//background color
        public string textColor { get; set; }//text color
    }
```

or you can manage colors on the client side -

```
scheduler.getEvent(id).textColor = "#ff0000";
```

you may also check 'CustomField' sample from the package

**UPDATE**

> Hi on using scheduler.getEvent(id).id = 5; the value is set but its not refreshed. And when the scheduler is dblclick,an add event forms pops up and only after that the event value is updated. How can I refresh the scheduler right after setting the value?

If it's still actual, event id shouldn't be changed directly, id binds to several internal things so modifying it can cause troubles. It's better to use scheduler.changeEventId method instead.

```
scheduler.changeEventId(oldId, newId);
```

after you've modified event, you can redraw it

```
scheduler.updateEvent(event_id);
```

or refresh the whole scheduler

```
scheduler.updateView();
```

Comment: Hi  on using scheduler.getEvent(id).id = 5; the value is set but its not refreshed. And when the scheduler is dblclick,an  add event forms pops up and  only after that the event value is updated. How can I refresh the scheduler right after setting the value?